# Path to iOS ‘On My iPod folder

Tags: ios, windows, ipod-touch, file-transfer

I have a iPod touch 6 running the latest version of iOS 12. I want to somehow copy a local folder onto my laptop. The folder have about 3800 images on it and it takes up about a gigabyte of storage. I tried to use iTunes, Google Drive, OneDrive, AirDrop, email and even plugging in the iPod directly and accessing the file system from there but I could not find where it has stored. It was a lot harder because I had 1+ GBs of data when the iPod only had 1 GB of RAM.

Does anybody know what the path is to the ‘On My iPod’ folder?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is Files app https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206481 available on ipod ? https://support.apple.com/guide/ipod-touch/transfer-files-with-itunes-iphf2d851b9/12.0/ios/12.0

Comment: Your computer a Mac or PC? And what OS? I believe on a PC the iPod is mounted in Windows Explorer and you have direct access to the pictures folder. Also why can't you just sync the iPod? That will copy all images (and songs, and...) to the computer allowing you to then delete what you want.

Comment: @SteveChambers It is a Windows 10 computer and also the pictures are stored in Files, not Photos. iTunes just says the iPod is not set up even though it is.